# Función que tome números arbitrarios y retorne una lista que contenga los argumentos que son número par

Tags: python

ya probé varias formas y ninguna me resulta:

```
def numeros_arbitrarios (*kwargs):

    lista = []
    if kwargs%2==0:
        lista.append(kwargs)

numeros_arbitrarios (1,2,3)
```

Soy consciente de que el código que puse es inútil, pero lo puse para que vieran mejor a que me refiero respecto al problema

Answer (score 1):

El problema de tu código, es que realmente no estas iterando por los argumentos recibidos, te falta ciclar a partir de `kwargs`. El otro problema que veo, es que tampoco estarías retornando `lista` que es dónde almacenas los números pares. Con esas correcciones tu código podría quedar así:

```
def numeros_arbitrarios (*kwargs):

    lista = []
    for arg in kwargs: 
      if arg % 2==0:
          lista.append(arg)

    return lista
```

Adicionalmente, en python puedes usar lo que se conoce como comprensión de listas, que permite escribir lo mismo de una forma mucho más compacta y expresiva:

```
def numeros_arbitrarios (*kwargs):

  return [arg for arg in kwargs if arg % 2==0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a recibir un número a la vez la lista debería venir de afuera porque si no la perderías y cada vez que llamas a esa función iniciaría una nueva, para verificar si el número es par podrías hacer:

If (numero % 2) == 0:
Y acá agregarlo a la lista.

Si vas a recibir una lista de números tendrías que recorrer la lista con un for:

for num in lista:
Agregar numero a la lista resultante

No olvides el return al final de la función.